# How do I get a connection string from Azure App Service configuration in a .Net Frame Asp.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a standard .Net Framework Asp.Net application deployed in an Azure App Service.
Within the Azure configuration, I've set up a couple environment variables and a connection string.

I'm able to retrieve the environment variables correctly at runtime.

```
var value = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppSettingTest");
```

How do you I retrieve the connection string?

This application IS NOT Asp.Net Core. I am not using dependency injection and a startup class. I could store that value in an environment variable, but I'm led to believe connection strings stored in the App Service configuration connection string is more secure.

Comment: Environment variables in Azure App Service are prefixed with `APPSETTING_`, `SQLCONNSTR_`, etc. You can find the [full list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#variable-prefixes)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - Spot on, works like a charm, thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use azure app service env variables inside my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949224/how-do-i-use-azure-app-service-env-variables-inside-my-application)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - Yes it does, see previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was added automatically when I marked this as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Andrew Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363967/andrew-williamson) and [JohnB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784988/johnb) posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

Environmental variables in Azure App Service are prefixed with `APPSETTING_`, `SQLCONNSTR_`, etc. complete list is available here [full list here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#variable-prefixes)