# Configure NLog and JS Exceptions with Application Insights

Tags: javascript, azure, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights, nlog

I have set up NLog to work with Applicatin Insights and also log js exceptions and is working as required. However, I am struggling with making the instrumentation key dynamic so it targets the environment specific application insight instance.

NLog config target

```
<target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget"
     layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}">
      <instrumentationKey>"mydevappinsightinstrumentationkey"</instrumentationKey>
      <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
    </target>
```

Layout cshtm for JS exceptions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        !function (v, y, T) { var S = v.location, k = "script", D = "instrumentationKey", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = (D[b](), "crossOrigin"), N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = T.name || "appInsights", n = ((T.name || v[e]) && (v[e] = t), v[t] || function (l) { var u = !1, d = !1, g = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "6", version: 2, config: l }; function m(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (g.sv || g.version), { time: (a = new Date).getUTCFullYear() + "-" + i(1 + a.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + i(a.getUTCDate()) + "T" + i(a.getUTCHours()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + i(a.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + (a.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) + "Z", iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } }; function i(e) { e = "" + e; return 1 === e.length ? "0" + e : e } } var e, n, f = l.url || T.src; function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, o, s, r, c, p; u = !0, g.queue = [], d || (d = !0, i = f, r = (c = function () { var e, t = {}, n = l.connectionString; if (n) for (var a = n.split(";"), i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { var o = a[i].split("="); 2 === o.length && (t[o[0][b]()] = o[1]) } return t[C] || (t[C] = "https://" + ((e = (n = t.endpointsuffix) ? t.location : null) ? e + "." : "") + "dc." + (n || "services.visualstudio.com")), t }()).instrumentationkey || l[D] || "", c = (c = c[C]) ? c + "/v2/track" : l.endpointUrl, (p = []).push((t = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", n = i, o = c, (s = (a = m(r, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", s.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: t.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: t + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + n + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + o, parsedStack: [] }], a)), p.push((s = i, t = c, (o = (n = m(r, "Message")).data).baseType = "MessageData", (a = o.baseData).message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + s + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', a.properties = { endpoint: t }, n)), i = p, r = c, JSON && ((o = v.fetch) && !T.useXhr ? o(r, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(i), mode: "cors" }) : XMLHttpRequest && ((s = new XMLHttpRequest).open(N, r), s.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), s.send(JSON.stringify(i))))) } function i(e, t) { d || setTimeout(function () { !t && g.core || a() }, 500) } f && ((n = y.createElement(k)).src = f, !(o = T[w]) && "" !== o || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = o), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, e = n, T.ld < 0 ? y.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function () { y.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, T.ld || 0)); try { g.cookie = y.cookie } catch (h) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { g[t] = function () { var e = arguments; u || g.queue.push(function () { g[t].apply(g, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var s, r, o = "track", c = "TrackPage", p = "TrackEvent", o = (t([o + "Event", o + "PageView", o + "Exception", o + "Trace", o + "DependencyData", o + "Metric", o + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + c, "stop" + c, "start" + p, "stop" + p, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), g.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }, (l.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}); return !0 !== l[I] && !0 !== o[I] && (t(["_" + (s = "onerror")]), r = v[s], v[s] = function (e, t, n, a, i) { var o = r && r(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== o && g["_" + s]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i, evt: v.event }), o }, l.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0), g }(T.cfg)); function a() { T.onInit && T.onInit(n) } (v[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {
            src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",

            crossOrigin: "anonymous",

            cfg: {
                connectionString: "InstrumentationKey=mydevappinsightinstrumentationkey;IngestionEndpoint=mydevappinsightingestionendpoint"
            }

        });

        window.appInsights = appInsights;
        appInsights.trackPageView();
        try {
            throw new Error("Logging Exception from Javascript");
        } catch (error) {
            appInsights.trackException("Logging Exception from Javascript.");
            appInsights.trackException({ error });
        }
    </script>
```

How do I make the instrumentation key dynamic in the above scenarios?

Comment: with Azure application insights key we use ```var instrumentationKey = "@instrumentationKey";```

Comment: ```@{
    // Determine the environment (development, production, etc.)
    string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");


    string developmentInstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY_DEVELOPMENT");
    string productionInstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY_PRODUCTION");

 
    string instrumentationKey = environment == "Production"
        ? productionInstrumentationKey
        : developmentInstrumentationKey;
}
```

Comment: @Luky ```set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development```
```set APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY_DEVELOPMENT=your_development_instrumentation_key```

Comment: @Sampath Thank you so much, I have added a comment on your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Layout cshtml you can do the following:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

connectionString: @Json.Serialize(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["ConnectionString"])
```

In my azure app service configuration, appsetting name is present in the following format:
ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString
and if reading from appsettings.json it should be in the following format:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "your app insight connection string here"
  }
```

In Nlog config if you want to make the instrumentation key dynamic

${configsetting:item=ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey}

So your target will become:

```
<target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget"
     layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}">
      <instrumentationKey>${configsetting:item=ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey}</instrumentationKey>
      <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
    </target>
```

Again ensure the same set up for app service configuration or appsetting json as I have shown in layout cshtml solution, only difference you will have is InstrumentationKey instead of ConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

The instrumentation key can be set to dynamic so it targets the environment-specific application insight instance like below.

```js
const config = require('config');
const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');

// Determine the environment (development, production, etc.)
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

// Get the instrumentation key from the configuration based on the environment
const instrumentationKey = config.get('appInsightsInstrumentationKey');

// Initialize Application Insights with the dynamic instrumentation key
appInsights
  .setup(instrumentationKey)
  .start();
```

- Install `npm install applicationinsights config`
  mkdir config
- Create a `config` directory within your project to store environment-specific configuration files.

`mkdir config`

**Configure Application Insights**

In your Azure portal, create an Application Insights resource if you haven't already. You'll need the instrumentation key for this resource.

**Create Configuration Files**

Inside the `config` directory, create two configuration files: `development.json` and `production.json`. Replace `"YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY"` and `"YOUR_PRODUCTION_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY"` with your actual instrumentation keys.

**development.json**

```json
{

"appInsightsInstrumentationKey_development":  "key "

}
```

- Run `set NODE_ENV=development` in bash and run the code.

**In Layout cshtm for JS:**

```
@{
    string instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    !function (v, y, T) {
    
            };

            // Rest of your script here...

            function a() {
                T.onInit && T.onInit(n)
            }

            (v[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a()
        })(window, document, {
            src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            cfg: {
                connectionString: "InstrumentationKey=" + @instrumentationKey + ";IngestionEndpoint=mydevappinsightingestionendpoint"
            }
        });

        window.appInsights = appInsights;
        appInsights.trackPageView();
        try {
            throw new Error("Logging Exception from Javascript");
        } catch (error) {
            appInsights.trackException("Logging Exception from Javascript.");
            appInsights.trackException({ error });
        }
    }(window, document, {});
</script>
```

[image]

- For more details [Refer](https://www.nexsoftsys.com/articles/integrating-apps-insights-with-nlog-aspnet-core.html) to this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226083/dynamically-reading-azure-app-configuration-in-net-core-web-app-using-net-6).

Comment: Hi Sampath, thank you for your detailed response. I was wondering can I not read appsetting value from azure app service or appsettings json directly in nlog config and in layout cshtml?

Comment: @Lucky If you define a value(or) application insights key in 'appsettings.json` it will be static like this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949224/how-do-I-use-azure-app-service-env-variables-inside-my-application) and to set dynamic targets that are environment-specific, you can go through the above steps for more information refer this [link](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-app-service-settings-from-environment).

Comment: In my set up I will be having a dedicated app insight instance for my web app in every environment and so I will have environment specific app setting json files / azure app service

Comment: you set env in Azure app service like this `configuration.template.json` in [example](https://github.com/catchco/azure-appservice-settings-env)

Comment: I am using ASPNETCORE ENVIRONMENT for it so it can use the appropriate appsetting json... But my question is I need to refer appsetting value in nlog config. I am trying like this in layout
```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration 
@Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["ConnectionString"]
```

Comment: I have not tried if it works I am going to try, I am looking for something similar in nlog config in the instrumentationKey  <target name="aiTarget" xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget"
     layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}">
      <instrumentationKey>myappinsightinstrumentationkey</instrumentationKey>
      <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
    </target>

Comment: For dot net with multiple env refer this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/environments.md#development-and-launchsettingsjson)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255257/discussion-between-lucky-and-sampath).